# Articles, a mistake in a job description

Tags: articles

I have found the following job description. I think there is a mistake, isn't it?

*FFF asset management is looking for an experienced analyst to join its team. The role requires a strong working knowledge of **THE** various asset classes with a specific focus on Fixed Income markets.*

They don't talk about any concrete company with their assets. They talk about it general. As a listener, I don't know anything about those assets classes.

I think there is no need in the.

**EDIT**

I searched in google for the exact expression and got the following results:

"knowledge of various asset classes" - 26 000 results

"knowledge of the various asset classes" - 98 results

Almost all job descriptions don't contain the.

Comment: it feels 'more streamlined' when you write it this way: The role requires a strong working knowledge of various asset classes ............ markets.

Comment: However, if the recruiter wants 'specific various asset classes' and assumes the readers know it well beforehand, then this 'the' may be used, though grammatically speaking, from the point of view of 'commoner/general reader' they won't know 'the various asset classes...."

Comment: the various asset classes (of the company) ***versus*** various assets classes (general statement using a plural noun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably there is a finite number of asset classes—and the job description wants the applicant to know all of them rather than just some of them.

Even if there is a variable number of asset classes in general, the job description could be talking about the specific number in use at the company. Although more context would be required to know that.

Note that according to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/assetclasses.asp), there seem to only be between three and six asset classes, a small enough number that the definite article could easily be used:

> **What is an 'Asset Class'**
>
> An asset class is a group of securities that exhibits similar characteristics, behaves similarly in the marketplace and is subject to the same laws and regulations. The three main asset classes are equities, or stocks; fixed income, or bonds; and cash equivalents, or money market instruments. Some investment professionals add real estate, commodities, and increasingly, cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, to the asset class mix.

---

Using the definite article is like saying a Quentin Tarantino film critic should know *the* Tarantino films.

Comment: I searched in google for the exact expression and got the following results:

"knowledge of various asset classes" - 26 000 results
"knowledge of the various asset classes" - 98 results

Almost all job descriptions dont contain the.

Comment: @Montroz Google searches are very poor indicators of grammar in most cases such as this. According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/assetclasses.asp), there are between three and six asset classes, depending on how they are broken down. This is easily a small enough number that the definite article can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without more context, but if they are looking for applicants with knowledge of every single asset class, then they are correct to say "knowledge of **the** various asset classes."

If they did not use **the**, then it would mean that they were looking for applicants with knowledge of at least two asset classes (just to make it the plural "classes"), but not necessarily all of them.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be googled because google does not show the reason why one might choose one or the other. This is, in fact, very simple:

- a strong working knowledge of the various asset classes (the company works with) ***versus***
- a strong working knowledge of various assets classes (general statement using a plural noun).
- a nice painting of **the** garden outside **the** house [there is only one]
- a nice painting of **the** gardens outside [there are several]
- a nice painting of garden**s** outside **the** house [not barns, for example]
- a nice painting of **a** garden outside **the** house [not a barn]

Answer (score 0):

Using THE in this sentence implies that there exists a specific set of generally known asset classes (all of which the applicant needs to know).  'various' here means that the asset classes differ from each other.  In other words, there are a variety of them.

If you omit the THE from that sentence, the meaning changes slightly.  Now 'various' means 'several', so the sentence would be asking for someone with knowledge of several asset classes.